# Newline character into textfile using QFile

Tags: qt, qt4

i want to put a newline into a txt file, i tried with many alternative with so many help from this forum but i am getting always unknown character always. Please help

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileDet.size(); i++) {
  qDebug() << "Name directory" << fileDet.at(i);
  QFile data("output.txt");
  if (data.open(QFile::Append)) {
    QTextStream out(&data);
    out << fileDet.at(i);  //<<'\n';
    out << QChar((int)'\n');
  }
  data.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i am getting always unknown character" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `out << endl;`

Comment: It's making flush, performance suffers, write '\n' instead or use `putChar`

Answer (score 8):

When you open the file:

> data.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text)

Comment: That fixes the issue. But how?

Comment: Do NOT work if you are using pure `QFile`, F.E.  `QFile file(path); file.open(QIODevice::Append | QFile::Text);  file.write("111111"); file.write("2222222");file.close();` out is on one! line.

Answer (score 0):

Very fast way using `QFile::putChar` :

```
file.putChar('\n');
```